# Set double click to my appointment using the AppointmentID

Tags: c#, vb.net, devexpress

I have a scheduler control to show the appointments in a timelineview and also have a table to show the appointments in a list so **I need to select an appointment in the list and automatically set double click on that appointment but from the scheduler**.

When I select an appointment from the table I can get his ID or any other field. Can I use the ID I get from the appointment in the table to select the appointment in the scheduler?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use ID from table into the scheduler but you have to be prepared. 
While creating scheduler and setting databindings or generating appointments in some kind of loop you have to set ID for each appointment and that ID should be the same as that in table of course. 
Then, if you already have focused ID from table you can use

```
schedulerStorage.Appointments.GetAppointmentById
```

and use instructions from this topic https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/DQ35569

I'm not sure what are you trying to do with that double click at appointment but if you want to open Appointment Editor you can use scheduler method

```
harmonogramScheduler.ShowEditAppointmentForm
```

while you already have an appointment.

Let me know if I understood you well.

Comment: Thanks Pawel I got it =)

Comment: Glad to hear that ;)